# Configuring MongoDB cluster with Datadog

Tags: mongodb, datadog

I'm new to using datadog and not quiet too sure how the integration between mongodb and datadog work other than installing from the datadog integration button

My intention is to collect as much metrics and information as possible from the cluster (primary one for now) into datadog and decide if its the right choice for us using as monitoring

But it looks like it would want an agent configuration, tried to follow the docs from datadog but dont get much sense out it or where to configure the agent on other than I connect my cluster via MongoDB Compass

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Thanks

Tried following the docs but not getting anywhere with jy

Answer (score 0):

To integrate your MongoDB with Datadog

- Go to your DD Account - Integrations
- Search for `mongo` - see the below screenshot
  [image]
- Select your desired Mongo integration type - `MongoDB` if you're using an on-prem Server or `MongoDB Atlas` if using MongoAtlas SaaS.

  - Follow the instructions in the **Config** tab of the opened window.

From my experience integrating MongoDB Atlas, it was as simple as

1. Creating an API Key in Datadog user/organization Settings.
2. Going to MongoAtlas relevant Project page, click on the project three dots menu, and select **Integrations**. Find and click on the `Datadog Integration`'s **Configure**, and configure it simply by pasting the API Key (copied from previous step) and selecting the relevant DD Region you are using.

***Note:*** If you are using an on-prem Mongo server, first you need to deploy the Datadog agent (recommended to be on the same instance the DB is running) and then follow the configuration instructions as explained in the Datadog Integrations module's **Config** tab.

Deploying DD Agent can be done in several ways such as: deploying as a Systemd Daemon (simplest approach if you are not familiar with the later options), as a container, or as a Kubernetes DaemonSet.

If you are not familiar with Datadog and/or the Agent deployment/configurations, I'd suggest using the official documentation or contacting their Support Team.

I hope this answer provides some hints and clues on the global perspective. Good luck.